# Pl/SQL procedure with single Parameter

Tags: plsql, procedure

I have create the following tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Actor
(Actor_ID CHAR(5),
lastName CHAR(24),
firstName CHAR(24),
/

CREATE TABLE Movie
(movieID CHAR(3) ,
title CHAR(36),
year NUMBER,
/

CREATE TABLE Role
(roleID CHAR(5),
roleName CHAR(36),
actorID CHAR(5),
movieID CHAR(3))
/

CREATE TABLE Quote
(quoteID CHAR(4),
quoteCHAR CHAR(255))
/

CREATE TABLE RoleQuote
(roleID CHAR(5),
quoteID CHAR(4))
/

Then i created this schemas....

CREATE TYPE  ACTOR_QUOTE_TYPE AS OBJECT ( 
Movie_Title  CHAR(36),
Year NUMBER,
Role  CHAR(36),
Quote CHAR(255)
)
/

CREATE TYPE AQ_NT AS TABLE OF  ACTOR_QUOTE_TYPE
/

CREATE TABLE ACTOR_QUOTES (
ACTORID CHAR(5),
QUOTES  AQ_NT
)  NESTED TABLE QUOTES STORE AS ACTOR_QUOTES_NT
/
```

I need to create a procedure with a single parameter(ACTORID is procedure parameter) and insert all the quotes in all the movies for any ACTORID, into the row(s) (an actor may have many movies and many quotes, some may have no quotes!) of the QUOTES nested table in the ACTOR_QUOTES table for any ACTORID.

How do i do it ?

Thanks

So far i tried  this, i am not sure it is correct or not.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Populate_Movies_Quote
AS
CURSOR Quote_cursor (ActorID in CHAR) IS
SELECT ActorID, Quote, Movie_Title from Actor_Quotes, AQ_NT where  Quotes.ActorID=ActorID;
BEGIN 
FOR row IN Quote_cursor
LOOP
INSERT INTO ACTOR_QUOTES (ActorID, quotes) values (row.ActorID,  AQ_NT(Actor_Quote_Type)); 
END LOOP; 
END Populate_Movies_Quote ;
/ 


Show erros


LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
4/55     PL/SQL: ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not
     allowed here

6/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
6/10     PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
     'QUOTE_CURSOR'
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried). I'd also recommend [ask].

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such

Comment: More or less duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946383/pl-sql-procedure-using-cursor-loops-and-single-parameter and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929058/sql-procedure-cursor-loops and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928363/pl-sql-cursor-loops If this is an assignment you guys should learn to search or (even better) just talk to each other.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly looks familiar. I take it someone else is stuck with Paul Judges Assignment too.

Without doing this for you here's the basic strategy I took.

First just write a select query that returns Movie Title, Movie Year, Role Name, and the Quote for a given Actor ID in that order. Forget about the procedure for now just get this select statement working. It means joining all the tables in the where clause.

If you achieve that then you basically have all the data that needs to be inserted into the nested table.

You can access the nested table for insertion by using the table function. So something like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE(SELECT QUOTES FROM Actor_Quotes WHERE ActorID = Actor_ID)
```

Where "Actor_ID" is the name of your procedures parameter. PL/SQL actually lets you insert into a table values directly from a select statement. You just have to ensure the values returned by the select statement match the order and type that your insert statement is expecting. This is pretty handy as it means there is no need for a cursor loop. So essentially all you have to do is place the select statement I said to write earlier directly below the above insert statement and you should be sorted. Make sure you use the same Actor_ID Parameter in your select query though.

Comment: Select ActorID, Movie_Title, Year, Role, Quote from Actor_Quotes, AQ_NT where Actor_Quotes.ActorID=AQ_NT.ActorID;                        Is it correct ?

Comment: Not quite. Remember you're selecting the data from the original tables and inserting it into the new nested table created later in the assignment. You'll probably have to use aliases and make sure you pay attention to the fields required.

Comment: Select a.ActorID, a.lastName, a.firstName, a.middleName, m.title, m.year, r.roleName, q.quoteCHAR from  Actor a, Movie m, RoleQuote rq, Quote q, Role r where and q.QuoteID=rq.QuoteID
   and rq.RoleID = r.RoleID
   and r.MovieID = m.MovieID  and a.ActorID= R.ActorID;              Is it correct not

Comment: Have you tried it? Does it get you the items you need to insert into the nested table? I'm not going to do it for you.